# Можно ли с помощью функции fopen() открывать файлы с заданным расширением в Windows?

Tags: c, windows, файлы, fopen

нужна помощь, я написала программу, которая открывает файл и записывает в него какое-то значение, но можно ли это сделать немного по другому, например, у меня есть много `.txt` файлов и мне нужно все имена этих файлов указывать в программе, можно ли обойтись без этого и открыть все файлы с расширением `.txt` и записать значение во все файлы с расширением `.txt`.
Используется язык программирования Си.

Comment: Перебрать файлы в каталоге по заданному шаблону в цикле...

Comment: То-есть, я могу указать расширение файлов и просто перебрать их с помощью цикла?

Comment: Не расширение, а шаблон имени. `*.txt`. Или перебрать все, и для каждого тестировать имя на соответствие шаблону - я фиг знает, что там есть в сях для работы с файловой системой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли с помощью функции fopen() открывать файлы с заданным расширением в Windows?

Можно. И даже нужно - потому что другого способа открыть не открытый еще файл язык не предоставляет (если, конечно, не использовать API операционной системы). Если, конечно, эти файлы существуют, и вы имеете право их открывать (например, не получится открыть для записи уже открытый с эксклюзивным доступом файл).

> можно ли обойтись без этого и открыть все файлы с расширением .txt

Не уточнено - в данном каталоге? На диске? На компьютере вообще? В любом случае вы должны открыть каждый файл *отдельно*. Нельзя открыть одновременно несколько файлов.

А чтобы открыть, скажем, все файлы в каталоге - надо все их найти. Для этого есть разные методы. Например, POSIX-функции `closedir`, `opendir`, `readdir`, `rewinddir` (см. [здесь](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/closedir-opendir-readdir-rewinddir)). Или функции API/

Находя все файлы и выполняя действие для каждого отдельно, вы решаете свою задачу.

Если я верно понял вашу проблему :)

Например, для текущего каталога поиск и вывод имен всех *.txt-файлов в Visual C++ выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    _finddata_t f;
    intptr_t h = _findfirst("*.txt",&f);
    if (h)
    {
        int nxt;
        do
        {
            if ((f.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) == 0)
                printf("%s\n",f.name);
            // Работа в файлом f.name
            nxt = _findnext(h,&f);
        } while(nxt == 0);
        _findclose(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, точно, забыла указать, открыть файлы с расширением .txt именно на диске

Comment: На **всем** диске? Во всех подкаталогах? тогда нужно использовать поиск рекурсивно...

Comment: Но, вот только как этот поиск ещё реализовать, не понятно(

Comment: Намек см. в обновленном ответе. Рекурсия - добавляйте точно такой же поиск всех каталогов, переходите в подкаталоги и продолжайте искать в них...

Comment: Хм, хорошо, буду разбираться, спасибо вам!